# Exclude default header parameters added with Swashbuckle (OpenApiParameter) for some specific controllers

Tags: c#, .net-core, openapi, swashbuckle

Is there any way to exclude some of the controllers from using default mandatory headers added as 'OpenApiParameter'? I have added the required header parameter to all end-points by:

```
public class RequiredHeadersFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        operation.Parameters.Add(
            new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "my-default-header",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Required = true,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "string"
                } 
            });
    }
}
```

But I need to exclude my "NoHeaderNeedController" in some way.
Is that possible to manage in OpenApiParameters or when registering it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. Realized that IOperationFilter was actually running for every each method and thereby just fetched out the controller name from the OperationFilterContext and just did a check on that:

```
    var controllerName = (context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor)?.ControllerName;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controllerName) && !controllerName.StartsWith("NoHeaderNeed"))
        {
            operation.Parameters.Add(
                new OpenApiParameter
                {
                    Name = "my-default-header",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Required = true,
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    }
                });
        }
```